# How to debug ctypes call of c++ dll?

Tags: c#, c++, python, dll

in my python project I call a c++ dll using ctypes library.
That c++ dll consists on a wrapper dll that calls methods of a c# com interop dll.

Sometimes I have a COM exception. I like to see what it corresponds exactlly but I don't know how to do it?

How can I attach the c++ debugger to this situation?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about your direct question, but maybe you could get around it by using [comtypes](http://sourceforge.net/projects/comtypes/) to go straight from COM to Python instead sticking C++ in between.

Then all you have to do is:

```
>>> from comtypes import client, COMError
>>> myclassinst = client.CreateObject('MyCOMClass.MyCOMClass')
>>> try:
...     myclassinst.DoInvalidOperation()
... except COMError as e:
...     print e.args
...     print e.hresult
...     print e.text
...
(-2147205118, None, (u'MyCOMClass: An Error Message', u'MyCOMClass.MyCOMClass.1', None, 0, None))
-2147205118
None
```

Comment: but then can I get more info about what exception will be? Cause if you don't know, in this case, any exception gave by the c++ calls are COM exceptions ^^

Comment: Yes; You get all the information that was included with the original exception, as members of the COMError object.

Comment: Edited to show how you can get the extra info from the COMError object.